# Linked Server Issues SQL Server to Oracle

Tags: sql-server, oracle, availability-groups, linked-server, oledb

I am trying to set up a linked server from SQL Server Production to one of our Oracle instances but experiencing this error : [image]

The test connection in ODBC succeeds, but it fails on SQL Server side. I have checked the following things:

1. OLEDB provider is installed
2. OLEDB bit matches the bit of SQL
3. OLEDB is registered
4. Linked server properties is the last option to be able to login in using username and password
5. Oracle provider has Allow In process checked
6. Oracle ports are opened
7. The right version client is installed

Are there anything else I should check further to resolve this error? Please provide me suggestions if you have experienced this before and what has worked for you. TIA

Comment: Do you see any failed login attempt registered on Oracle side?

Comment: No at that time, it was not even hitting Oracle side. However, our solution was to restart the SQL service and it had worked.